# Use counter as part of variable

Tags: php, variables, for-loop, counter

Here's what I'd like to do

```
for($i = 1; $i < 4; $i++) {

    $featuredImage$i = $featured['featuredImage$i'];
    $featuredText$i  = $featured['featuredText$i'];
    $featuredURL$i   = $featured['featuredURL$i'];

    }
```

How can do I something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only thing you need is to learn PHP language.
This page contains everything you need: http://php.net/types.string
It worth reading regardless this particular question, as string syntax is one of most basic PHP syntax concepts and you have to learn it by heart anyway.

<s>The only note I have to add: strictly speaking, you're gonna use a counter not as a part of *variable* but as a part of *string*, which, in it's turn, gonna be a key for the array variable. But syntactically you're composing a string out of a string and a variable.</s>

**EDIT**

Oh. I didn't notice leftmost variable.
Only when I started writing another suggestion, I was able to see it.

Well, you may also consider using nested array.
It could be used this way

```
foreach ($featured as $item) {

    echo $item['featuredImage'];
    echo $item['featuredText'];
    echo $item['featuredURL'];
}
```

or do whatever you want to do with these variables.

It would be nice to see the full context which lead you to this question, thus it will be possible to give you best solution for your particular case.
May be you will need dramatically redesign your database...

Comment: Stack Overflow will be even more full of questions like this if you don't read the docs.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using an array along with the suggestion posted by andreas. I found that putting the string variable into an array, then calling that out in the same type of for loop later in the code did exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

Something like

```
for($i = 1; $i < 4; $i++) {

    ${featuredImage . $i} = $featured['featuredImage' . $i];
    ${featuredText. $i}  = $featured['featuredText' . $i];
    ${featuredURL . $i}   = $featured['featuredURL' . $i];

    }
```

Comment: Hz possible it?? without this:: $featuredImage.$i

Answer (score 1):

You need to concatenate the variable onto the end of the string, as so:

```
for($i = 1; $i < 4; $i++) {

    $featuredImage$i = $featured['featuredImage'.$i];
    $featuredText$i  = $featured['featuredText'.$i];
    $featuredURL$i   = $featured['featuredURL'.$i];

}
```

Remember, variables cannot be used inside strings with single quotes, if you wanted to put a variable within a string use double quotes instead, for example:

```
$world="World!";
$str1='Hello $world'; // outputs "Hello $world"
$str2="Hello $world"; // outputs "Hello World!"
```

You can use variables inside strings with doubles quotes, sometimes this is easier than breaking in and out of the string, however with single quotes you must concatenate it in place;

Comment: Thanks for actually explaining where my problem was. Helped me understand what I needed to change. I voted up.

Answer (score 1):

These will work:

```
for($i = 1; $i < 4; $i++) {
    $featuredImage$i = $featured["featuredImage$i"];   // $variable works inside double quotes
    $featuredText$i  = $featured['featuredText' . $i]; // single quote and string concatenation
    $featuredURL$i   = $featured["featuredURL{$i}"];   // $variable can be enclosed inside {} for cases such as $featured["featuredURL{$i}_href"]
                                                       // to have php substitute the variable $i instead of $i_href
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i got Answer : Try it

```
${"featuredImage" . $i} = $featured['featuredImage' . $i];
${"featuredText". $i}  = $featured['featuredText' . $i];
${"featuredURL" . $i}   = $featured['featuredURL' . $i];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i = 1; $i < 4; $i++) {

    $featuredImage$i = $featured['featuredImage' .$i];
    $featuredText$i  = $featured['featuredText' .$i];
    $featuredURL$i   = $featured['featuredURL' .$i];

    }
```