# add a counter variable to a variable name

Tags: php, string, if-statement, for-loop

I don't understand how one can add a counter variable content to the name of another variable. Although I realized that my problem could be solved more elegantly with the use of arrays, I want to use the counter in the variable name.

My code looks like this so far:

```
    <?php
        $f2 = bla2;
        $f3 = bla3;
```

....

```
        $f13 = bla13;
        $f14 = 0;
        echo $f2;
        for($j = 3; $j <= 14; ++$j){
        if (!empty('$f'.$j)){
        echo(', ');
        eval('print $f'.$j.';');
        };
     };
     ?>
```

I want to give output for every $f and also check if it's empty before I echo it. The for loop already worked before adding the if condition. I assume that I don't name the variable correctly inside the if condition and I have no clue how to do it, as this code doesn't work as it is now.

I would also like to know, if I could include the if condition into the for loop.
I already tried to apply the solutions to these questions

[Access a variable using a counter as part of the variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4327218/access-a-variable-using-a-counter-as-part-of-the-variable-name)

[Add counter to the end of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12664712/add-counter-to-the-end-of-variables/12664734#12664734)

[Use counter as part of variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990901/use-counter-as-part-of-variable/4990922#4990922)

but had no success so far. Maybe someone finds my mistake here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
for ($i = 3; $i <= 14; ++$i) {
    if (empty(${"f$i"})) {
        ${"f$i"} = ${"bla$i"}();
    }
}
```

The bottom line is that you can use `${"f$i"}` to find your variable variable.